# A professor is happy to supervise me. Does that mean my formal application will be accepted?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-kingdom

I am worried since, in fact, I do not meet the minimum grade requirements for a PhD admission of the school. But the supervisor says they are happy to offer me a funded PhD. Note : this is in the UK.

Comment: You are accepted when you receive the acceptance letter. Until then, nothing counts.

Comment: In UK, the professor's word does count. If the prof. is interested, then everything else is just a formality (usually).

Comment: @Faustus Please note that the OP states that "_I do not meet[d] the minimum grade requirements_' . It's exactly the formality I am concerned about.

Comment: Does your potential supervisor know *in no uncertain terms* that you do not meet the grade requirements? Even if he or she has seen your grade transcript, you cannot take it for granted that they have considered this aspect. You will likely need their support in order to gain admission.

Comment: The university has a "minimum grade requirement" for admissions to the Ph.D. program?

Comment: @Faustus _Everything else is a formality (usually)_ — This is a good working definition of "not counting".

Answer (score 8):

It isn't guaranteed.

The fact that you have a professor who is willing to be your supervisor is a strong factor in your favour -- very strong.

However, there may be other requirements that means a student can't be accepted onto an institution's PhD program. These include language ability, suitable visa or residency requirements, and, of course, how strictly the institution adheres to whether you satisfy the minimum academic requirements. In some cases, the proposed supervisor's influence overcomes these. In others, it does not.

The head of department in some cases has the final say as to whether a student is to be accepted into the PhD programme. It is unlikely, but not impossible, that an HoD would deny the student onto the programme, irrespective of the professor's support.